# Is it possible to set the volume of the media player by using Appium

Tags: appium

my application is a media player application,on automating the application i need to control the media volume up and down

i have tried with adb commands in my program but it not worked , can any one please help me on this.

code :

public void devicevolume()throws IOException, InterruptedException{

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime()
            .exec("adb - KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN");

    p.waitFor();
    p.destroy();

}
```

Comment: Have you succeeded in using this adb command from command line?

Comment: didn't try that

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try through adb commands:

you can call setMasterVolume() with

```
service call audio <code> i32 <volume>
```

The codes are version specific. Let's say you want to set volume to 50% on a KitKat device. The command will be:

```
service call audio 9 i32 50
```

read ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/… to find out the proper code for your android version

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Android driver and pass the key event for increasing and decreasing the device volume

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).